# How do I replace key coincidences only in square brackets?

Tags: javascript, string, object

I'm working on some function that replaces occurrences of a string enclosed in square brackets that matches a key, with its corresponding value from a given object, but I don't know how to replace only those strings inside the square brackets, it replaces everything, I would appreciate your help:

This is what I have tried so far:

```
function template(str, obj){
  let new_str = str;

  for (let key in obj) 
  {
       new_str = new_str.replace(new RegExp(key, 'g'), obj[key]);
  }
 console.log(new_str);
}

template("Hi [name], your balance is [balance]", { name: "Joe", balance: 1200 });
```

I'm getting :

```
"Hi [Joe], your 1200 is [12000]"
```

but I expect:

```
"Hi Joe, your balance is 12000"
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the keys are enclosed in square brackets, you must put that into your pattern as well:

```js
function template(str, obj) {
  let new_str = str;

  for (let key in obj) {
    new_str = new_str.replace(new RegExp('\\[' + key + '\\]', 'g'), obj[key]);
  }
  console.log(new_str);
}

template("Hi [name], your balance is [balance]", {
  name: "Joe",
  balance: 1200
});
```

You also might consider using just a single regex with a replacer function, to simplify the code:

```js
const template = (str, obj) => str.replace(
  /\[([^\]]*)\]/g,
  (match, possibleKey) => obj[possibleKey] ? obj[possibleKey] : match
);

console.log(template("Hi [name], your balance is [balance]", {
  name: "Joe",
  balance: 1200
}));
```

If what is contained in the square brackets will always exist in the object, then there's no need for the conditional operator:

```js
const template = (str, obj) => str.replace(
  /\[([^\]]*)\]/g,
  (_, key) => obj[key]
);

console.log(template("Hi [name], your balance is [balance]", {
  name: "Joe",
  balance: 1200
}));
```

Comment: Really cool solution!, I am not familiar with functional programming yet, Can you explain to me how your nested arrow functions work? Thanks.

Comment: It's basically just a method I used to reduce syntax noise - arrow functions can have implicit return, and are more concise than full-fledged `function`s. The expression that follows the `=>` will be returned immediately, without requiring a `return` statement

Comment: Maybe just me (there's always more than one way to go about it) but I would prefer the regular expression `/\[(.*?)\]/g` The lazy quantifier is more concise.

Comment: @Wyck It is more concise, but it's also less efficient. Consider [lazy, 44 steps](https://regex101.com/r/cIQhgX/1) vs [greedy, 4 steps](https://regex101.com/r/cIQhgX/2/). With certain patterns, it can result in an order-of-magnitude difference. Performance doesn't matter in most situations, but it's just a habit I got into

Comment: When an answer solves your problem, you can consider marking it as Accepted to indicate that your issue is resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

You need match `[]` too. Use template literals and wrap the key in `[]` in your `RegExp`

```js
function template(str, obj){
  let new_str = str;

  for (let key in obj) 
  {
       new_str = new_str.replace(new RegExp(`\\[${key}\\]`, 'g'), obj[key]);
  }
 console.log(new_str);
}

template("Hi [name], your balance is [balance]", { name: "Joe", balance: 1200 });
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I wouldn't think about using template literals, simple solution but effective